# Asp.net add multiply rows to CRM 2011 (2+ clients/User)

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011

I've extended the customer portal from MS for 2011 with functionality to add an order.

Now i came across a problem when 2 or more user try to create an order at the same time.

first I created the SalesOrder with:

```
order = new SalesOrder();
order.SalesOrderId = OrderID;
order.Name = string.Format("Order {0}", DateTime.Now); 
order.CustomerId = parentCustomer;
order.PriceLevelId = priceLevel.ToEntityReference();

OrderID = XrmContext.Create(order);
```

and after this i added products(SalesOrderDetail) with a foreach:

```
foreach (var product in OrdredProducts)
{
    productToAdd = new SalesOrderDetail
    {
        SalesOrderId = new CrmEntityReference(SalesOrder.EntityLogicalName, 
                                              OrderID),
        ProductId = new EntityReference(Product.EntityLogicalName, 
                                        product.ProductID),
        Quantity = product.Quantity
    };
    XrmContext.Create(productToAdd);
}
```

this works fine when just one user orders something. But if 2+ users I get error for both user.

so I changed the code to this:

```
order = new SalesOrder();
OrderID = Guid.NewGuid();
order.SalesOrderId = OrderID;
order.Name = string.Format("Order {0}", DateTime.Now); //:d
order.CustomerId = parentCustomer;
order.PriceLevelId = priceLevel.ToEntityReference();
XrmContext.AddObject(order);

foreach (var product in OrdredProducts)
{
    productToAdd = new SalesOrderDetail
    {
        SalesOrderId = new CrmEntityReference(SalesOrder.EntityLogicalName, 
                                              OrderID),
        ProductId = new EntityReference(Product.EntityLogicalName, 
                                        product.ProductID),
        Quantity = product.Quantity
    };
    XrmContext.AddObject(productToAdd);
}

XrmContext.SaveChanges();
```

Now if 2+ Users orders something, just one User fails not both like the first try.

the Errors I've got as far(every time an other one):

- ValidateOpen - Encountered disposed CrmDbConnection when it should not be disposed
- SQL timeout expired.
- An unexpected error occurred.
- Error retrieving next number (currentordernumber) for organization {guid): return value is empty
- System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #F60BF6A2

does anyone have some suggestion where the problem could be? is it the SQL Server/CRM Server/IIS/my code or something different?

**Additional Information**

- SQL Server and CRM Server are not on same machine
- I get the same error when i test in VS2012 server(back-end is the same SQL/CRM server)
- i get the same error when one user runs over IIS and one over VS2012(debugg)

**edit**
XrmContext is a XrmServiceContext type and this is derived from CrmOrganizationServiceContext and this one is generated with the crmsvcutil

Comment: check if there are synchronous plugins attached to the create message for salesorder and salesorderdetail. At first sight your code looks ok.

Comment: we had one but i already disabled it

Comment: How are you creating your IOrganizationService/XrmContext?  Any chance you're sharing a single instance on multiple threads?

Comment: Im using xrmcontext from customer portal, i will edit my question when im at a pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone gets the same problem i solved it following:

first i created the SalesOrder and added it to the CRM:

```
public void AddToCrm(Entity entity)
{
     XrmContext.AddObject(entity);
}
```

then I created all Orders(SalesOrderDetail) and added them to the CRM(same function as above).
And finally i saved it:

```
public void SaveToCrm()
{
    XrmContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

this behaviour is like a transaction in the database.
so all other Order have to wait till this one is done.